# ISC DHCP primary ip using a variable

Tags: dhcp

How can I define my DHCP zone using a variable instead of an IP address or name (in /etc/hosts):

Instead of :

```
zone z.example.com {
     primary 192.168.0.1;
     secondary 192.168.0.2;
}
```

Defining a primaryIPAddress and secondaryIPAddress in a conf file:

```
zone z.example.com {
     primary primaryIPAddress;
     secondary secondaryIPAddress;
}
```

Comment: Where would the content of the variable be stored? In the same config file? Somewhere else?

Comment: In a file located under /etc/dhcp and included in the /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

Comment: I can already do that for a key for instance, and I am lookig for an equivalent for an IP address. The aim is to have a separated file where the IPs are stored and be able to change it easyly.